# Graph API: Is it possible to get Facebook members' names and location in a Facebook group which I am a member too?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I need to get the names and location of a Facebook group which I am also a member in it. I could see most of the member names and their location but I could not seems to be able to get the data out from Graph API. May I know if it is possible to get these info from Graph API please? I am using Python 3 but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get all group members any more, the `/group/members` endpoint has been removed.

The [`groups_access_member_info`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-groups_access_member_info) permission allows to get data about individual group members from locations such as the group feed; but you would need to be a group admin to be able to use it.